# Upgrading SQL Server 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2008 running on my development machine that I wish to upgrade to the 2012 release.

In your experience, is it better to use the upgrade wizard or to remove the SQL Server 2008 and do a clean install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes certainly use the wizard. It will offer you a tidy upgrade, and can allow for side by side installation with server2008 - if that is something you want.
I would suggest sticking to the wizard.

Comment: +1 definitely use the wizard

Comment: I went ahead with the wizard, but the upgrade failed leaving me with 2 separate corrupt installations of 2008 and 2012. After spending the half day wiping all traces of them from my machine I've done a clean install and it has been working fine since. I'll accept this as an answer once MS patch this up.

Comment: Same here.  Upgrade failed, despite all checks indicating it should have succeeded.

Comment: Update: Uninstalling "SQL Server 2012 Native Client" and re-running the upgrade succeeded.  When looking at the installation date of this component in Control Panel / Add/Remove Programs, I noticed it was installed months earlier independently (not sure why).  I found this solution on another thread, so I wasn't the only person with this problem and solution.